# fprintf_s() is not appending to file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have the following code:

```
stream = _fsopen(m_runOptions.UsbtmVersionFile, "a", _SH_DENYNO);
fprintf_s(stream,"\n %s \n",appProductname);
fclose(stream);
```

when I look in the text file created it never creates a new line for print out.  It overwrites the existing line.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Aside from sudden `:` after `UsbtmVersionFile` and missing `_fsopen` result check this code seems to be correct.

Comment: sorry the : was a typo

Comment: What are the values of m_runOptions.UsbtmVersionFile, appProductname? If replace variables to const char* constants, will it work?

Comment: Alexey, I tried to flip it to const char and get compiler error?

Comment: @M.Hansen please post full source code and full compile error

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem. Can you write a complete, compilable program that demonstrates the problem? Makes sure that minimal code actually does reproduce the problem!

Comment: I can't show source code because its a secret machine.  so the problem is that m_runOptions.UsbtmVersionFile is not a const char*.   its name is derived from an ini input file.